# What events reset the wanted level in Assassin's Creed IV?

Tags: assassins-creed-4-black-flag

I was harvesting some resources to upgrade the Jackdaw and building up my wanted level on the high seas the other night.  I know I can lower this by bribing the proper NPC on shore or boarding a ship and choosing to reduce my wanted level.  In this case I am trying to build it up so pirate hunters start sending Man-O-Wars at me so I can beef up Kenway's Fleet.

I was not exclusively building my wanted level and was doing some story events, exploring, and harpooning along the way, but I eventually noticed I was back down to 1 mark on my wanted level.  I do not remember for sure what I did, but I am pretty sure I did not intentionally lower my wanted level.  Does doing story missions or exiting the game reset my wanted level?

Generally: Other than bribing and choosing to reduce it after boarding a ship, what events reduce or reset your wanted level?

Comment: Some story missions definitely reset your wanted level (and also ship health). I can't be sure of which ones though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The wanted level goes down on its own at a slow rate. It's difficult to notice if your preoccupied doing story missions or fishing.

As a general rule if you are out of combat with the navy they will give up the pursuit. So if you want to keep your wanted level high, pop a few gunboats/schooners along your travels.